# solving exception 'Missing sendPduHandle'

Tags: python, pysnmp

I am using PySNMP 4.2.5 together with cmdgen.AsynCommandGenerator(). The cmdGen.snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher() is running in an extra thread to call runDispatcher again when it terminates.
Sometimes the runDispatcher throws an exception about a Missing sendPduHandle, which is captured, but the same exception regarding the same PduHandle (same number) occurs very frequent then (~ 2 times per second).

How to get rid of that error?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is only safe to run a SNMP engine instance within a single thread. IF you want it running in multiple threads, you should have thread-local SNMP engine instance.

Here is [an example](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/advanced-topics.html#query-agents-from-multiple-threads) for pysnmp 4.3.x.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have not enough reputation to vote it. It is hard to hear that pysnmp is not thread safe because all snmp queries are executed as job of apsheduler at my side.